# Explain what means to join same table twice

Tags: sql

I was preparing for exam and I have this exercise that I don't understand

I have table of Clients that have ClientID,
and also I have table of Transactions that have Foreign Key referenced to Clients, SenderID and RecieverID (refering to ClientID)

I need to create view that will show Transactions with Sender name and Reciever Name, and I did it but I don't understand how it works and why

Here is code:

```
SELECT CS.Name [SenderName], CR.Name [RecieverName]
FROM Transactions T
INNER JOIN Clients CS
ON CS.ClientID = T.SenderID
INNER JOIN Clients CR
ON CR.ClientID = T.RecieverID
```

Comment: Clients table contains info about sender/receiver that is why you have 2 FKs from Transaction to Clients table

Comment: I need deeper explanation how this two inner join on same table works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you need  the name  (for sender or recevier ) you need  a relation based on the key between the  the transaction table and the clients table

you need  the name of the sender  ( first join with  Clients )  and the name for recevier  ( second join with  Clients )

for avoid confusion between the two (same name) table you need  an alias that let you join the specific related  tabe  .. you use CS and CR as table nale alias

in this way is as  you work with two differente table name  (or with a logical duplication of the same table)

```
 SELECT CS.Name [SenderName], CR.Name [RecieverName]
    FROM Transactions T
    INNER JOIN Clients CS  ON CS.ClientID = T.SenderID
    INNER JOIN Clients CR  ON CR.ClientID = T.RecieverID
```

You can thinks at the table content as  a set of data  ..so  you use two time the same set of data extracting the row  mathcing your relation each time.

Answer (score 0):

Each row in the table `Transactions` contains:
a `SenderID` which *points* to a row in the table `Clients` and
a `RecieverID` which *points* to **another** row in the table `Clients`.
So you must make one join of `Transactions` to `Clients` using `SenderID` to get the sender's name and another join to `Clients` using `RecieverID` to get the reciever's name.